# Blob from PDF File

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, blob

I receive a PDF using Angular Http from an external API with using Content Type: application/pdf. So a simple Get Request, nothing fancy.

Now I need to convert this into a Blob object. However it doesn't seem to work.

How can I accomplish this in JavaScript?

Somehow directly saying `let blobFile = new Blob(result)` or `let blobFile = new Blob([result])` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: how did you download the pdf? perhaps we can start from there..

Comment: You can convert the pdf to Base64 using Filereader , then that base64 can be converted into a blob.

Comment: did you set `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`? Otherwise, you **can't** create directly a blob istance.

Comment: are you getting bytearray in the response?

Comment: I updated my question for some questions

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the conversion when you do the request if the `Content-type` is `application/pdf`:

```
yourServiceMethod(): Promise<Blob> {
  return this.httpClient.get(your-url, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
}
```

from there, you can use a utility like [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to complete the download process to the client's machine:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

onDownload(): void {
  this.yourService.yourServiceMethod().then(file => {
    FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
  });
}
```